# Create custom post type on successful woocommerce order

Tags: custom-post-types, php, woocommerce-offtopic

On the checkout page I have a custom field that gets saved to the order meta data. I need to grab the order meta data and create a custom post type and fill the custom fields with order meta data.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
       global $mypass;
 echo '<p><strong>'.__('My Field').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'My Field', true ) . '</p>';
   $mypass = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'My Field', true );
}
```

The following functions creates the post on checkout but does not pull in the meta field set in the function above

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'create_custom_post' );
function create_custom_post($order, $order_id, $posts) {
  global $posts;
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Page Title',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_type' => 'sale',
);
$website_url =  get_post_meta($order_id->id, 'My Field', true);
$new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
update_post_meta($new_post_id, 'My Field', $website_url );
}
```

I have also tried to set a global variable on the function that saves the meta order data

```
function recent_post_page($order_status, $order_id, $post, $checkout ) {
global $mypass;
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Page title',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_type' => 'sale',
);

$new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
update_post_meta($new_post_id, 'My Field', $mypass );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'recent_post_page', 10, 2 );
```

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: `'post_type' => 'page'` you're creating a new Page post type, not a custom post. Have you registered your CPT?

Comment: I made a typo there, my main focus is to get the custom fields from order details meta data

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure it out by placing the wp_insert_post function in the same function that saves the order meta data

Answer (score 0):

Check out `$website_url =  get_post_meta($order_id->id, 'My Field', true);`  You're trying to get the `id` of `$order_id`.

`$order_id` is, or should be a string.  You will need to do either:

```
get_post_meta($order_id, 'My Field', true);
```

or

```
get_post_meta($order->ID, 'My Field', true);
```

Comment: Same issue, the value is empty for the field.